# cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation does not work on background in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I want to track user coordinates every 10 seconds in background so I used cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation.It works very well at the android in foreground or background but in IOS it does not work in background(it works only in foreground)

In background it does not fire success( SetLocationUpdates ) function and also it give not error,it does not fire error function.

here is my config.xml

```
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation"    source="npm" spec="2.4.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="2.3.0">
    <variable name="ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="xxx permission xx" />
</plugin>

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0" />
```

and here is my html page code

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

           document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
           function onDeviceReady () {

             backgroundGeolocation.configure(SetLocationUpdates, onError, {
            desiredAccuracy: 10,
            stationaryRadius:1,
            distanceFilter: 1,
            interval: 10000
        });
         backgroundGeolocation.start();
//backgroundGeolocation.switchMode(backgroundGeolocation.mode.FOREGROUND);

         }
         }


            function onError(error) {
            alert("error:"+error.message);

        }


           function SetLocationUpdates(position){

    //store position to database via ajax call.....
```

it works very well in foreground so i try to force it to foreground in switch mode but it does not work

```
backgroundGeolocation.switchMode(backgroundGeolocation.mode.FOREGROUND,switchModesuccess, switchModefail);
```

Comment: trying to implement the same; but in my case it does not work even in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are testing on iOS 11. As noted in [this issue](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/issues/324), the current version of this plugin does not work in the background on iOS 11.

Comment: yes I am testing on IOS 11 and in that link you provide( https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/issues/324 )  I asked.At the end of issue there is my problem...What should I do?I try other background but all of them has problem with IOS

Comment: I have found [cordova-background-geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/) to be the only out-of-the-box background geolocation plugin that works on iOS 11 and Android 8.

Comment: is it free for IOS?Ok thank you I will try it for IOS

Comment: it give build error..I just at this config.xml and add code to my html is is enough?   <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
 <plugin name="cordova-background-geolocation-lt" source="npm">
    <variable name="LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="xx" />
    <variable name="LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="xx" />
    <variable name="MOTION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="x" />
     </plugin>